# Model.update: initial empty array doesn't get updated properly

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a rather complex document with many optional properties, so I prefer to update the whole document.

However, I'm experiencing some issue with arrays, which are initial empty.

Partial model:

```
description: [{
    heading: String,
    text: String
}],
images: [{
    title: String,
    description: String,
    type: String,
    url: String
}],
```

Initial value:

```
description: [{
    heading: 'some heading',
    text: 'some text'
}],
images: [],
```

adding following object to images:

```
{
    description: "img text"
    title: "img title"
    type: "image/jpeg"
    url: "http://mybucket.amazonaws.com/images/img.jpg"
}
```

and updating with:

```
Paths.update(path, function(err, numberAffected, raw) {
    ...
}
```

**Update:**
where path is:

```
{ 
    customer_id: '52e1fa1b853285b2ad828152',
    name: 'Whitehorse Historic Buildings',
    polyline:
       [ [ 60.720551, -135.055365 ],
         [ 60.720551, -135.055365 ],
         ...
         [ 60.72057, -135.055426 ],
         [ 60.720561, -135.055407 ] ],
    poi:
       [ { name: 'Donnenworth House',
           latitude: 60.72053,
           longitude: -135.0555,
           audios: [],
           videos: [],
           images: [],
           description: [],
           streetview: [Object] },
         { name: 'Roundhouse',
           latitude: 60.72161,
           longitude: -135.0509,
           audios: [],
           videos: [],
           images: [],
           description: [],
           streetview: [Object] },
         { name: 'White Pass & Yukon Route Building',
           latitude: 60.72015,
           longitude: -135.0499,
           audios: [],
           videos: [],
           images: [],
           description: [],
           streetview: [Object] },
         { name: 'Berrigan Cabins',
           latitude: 60.71848,
           longitude: -135.0501,
           audios: [],
           videos: [],
           images: [],
           description: [],
           streetview: [Object] },
         { name: 'Log Skyscrappers',
           latitude: 60.71804,
           longitude: -135.0525,
           audios: [],
           videos: [],
           images: [],
           description: [],
           streetview: [Object] },
         { name: 'Old Log Church',
           latitude: 60.71828,
           longitude: -135.0541,
           audios: [],
           videos: [],
           images: [],
           description: [],
           streetview: [Object] },
         { name: 'Taylor House',
           latitude: 60.71889,
           longitude: -135.058,
           audios: [],
           videos: [],
           images: [],
           description: [],
           streetview: [Object] },
         { name: 'McKinnon House',
           latitude: 60.71973,
           longitude: -135.0607,
           audios: [],
           videos: [],
           images: [],
           description: [],
           streetview: [Object] },
         { name: 'Captain Martin House',
           latitude: 60.72051,
           longitude: -135.0561,
           audios: [],
           videos: [],
           images: [],
           description: [],
           streetview: [Object] } ],
     audios: [],
     videos: [],
     images:
         [ { title: 'img title',
             description: 'img desc',
             type: 'image/jpeg',
             url: 'http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/images/52e1fa1b853285b2ad828152-Whitehorse Historic Buildings-img.jpg' } ],
     description:
         [ { heading: 'Whitehorse Historic Buildings',
             text: 'A  historical walking tour offered by the Yukon Historical & Museums Association' } ] }
```

results in:

```
"images" : [  "[object Object]" ],
```

I'm able to add and update objects to the description array, which is initially not empty.

Is there something I'm doing wrong, or sounds this like a bug?

Comment: Can you show us your update query? (provides more context)

Comment: please refer to my update.

Comment: ’update’ needs two parameters before the callback. You have only one!

Comment: @heinob: I think you are right, however, if just one param is provided I would expect in the cb an err. In fact providing just this one param updates any property correctly, except a previously empty array. I have tried Paths.update({}, path, function(){...}), but same thing as with one param.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of debugging I figured out that Mongoose doesn't like the key word **type** in the model schema. After changing it my issue was resolved.

To my knowledge **type** is not a reserved keyword in JavaScript, and I think reserved words in Mongoose should be better documented.